# How do you search a hashmap with an object as a key?

Tags: java

Say we have class RegistrationPlate:

```
public class RegistrationPlate {
private final String regCode;
private final String country;

public RegistrationPlate(String country, String regCode) {
    this.regCode = regCode;
    this.country = country;
}

public String getRegCode() {
    return this.regCode;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return this.country;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return country + " " + regCode;
}
```

and I have a hashmap with RegistrationPlate as its key, and owner as its value. If I wanted to search this hashmap given a RegistrationPlate object as a parameter how would I do so? This is how I initially approached it:

```
HashMap<RegistrationPlate, owner> vehicleRegister = new HashMap<RegistrationPlate, owner>();


public String getOwner(RegistrationPlate plate) {
    if (this.vehicleRegister.containsKey(plate.getRegCode())) {
        return "The owner is: " + this.vehicleRegister.get(plate);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I thought the logic here would work because if the vehicleRegister contained the registrationcode string as a key it would return the string below. Is there a more clean-cut way of accessing the object in the hashmap?

Comment: What happens when you try to compile and run your code here?

Comment: Nothing. Compiles but it doesnt function when i call it in main

Comment: You should include the information in your previous comment as part of your question. You should also show your main method and wrap the `get()` method in the class which contains it.

Comment: "Say we have object RegistrationPlate with two instance variables:" The next line after this quote shows a constructor, not instance variables. It would help if you showed the actual class. It can be truncated to some extent to save space, but the main idea is to show code that can actually be compiled. None of the code you have shown here meets this criteria because there are no classes.

Comment: Should I still look to include the classes if i got it to work?

Comment: Yes, you should fix up this question so that it is helpful to future visitors. Also keep this in mind for future questions. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more suggestions about how much code to post in a question.

Comment: Is that why it was downvoted? lol

I saw a few other answers get downvoted and deleted as well. Was a bit confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `HashMap` has `RegistrationPlate` as keys, you cannot expect to find a `String` that is the key. This means that you should do

```
this.vehicleRegister.containsKey(plate)
```

instead of

```
this.vehicleRegister.containsKey(plate.getRegCode())
```

However, you can call `get()` directly without calling `containsKey()` first:

```
public String get(RegistrationPlate plate) {
    return "The owner is: " + this.vehicleRegister.get(plate);
}
```

More importantly, you must override `equals()` and `hashcode()` in `RegistrationPlate` order to get the behavior that you wish. Otherwise, the default implementations will be used which return `true` only when the key is a reference to the exact same instance as the on stored in the `HashMap`. This is rarely the case. You typically want to compare the **contents** of the reference instead.

Comment: If you override equals you should also make sure to override hashCode

Comment: So it would be as simple as:         return "The owner is: " + this.register.get(plate);? 

And assuming I overrode equal and hashcode properly; Would my code above work properly if I call equals() instead of containsKey()?

Comment: @AeriaGlorisia `equals()` and `containsKey()` do two completely different things. "Correctness" depends on the purpose of your `get()` method.

Comment: @AeriaGlorisia See the code in my most recent edit. This will now compile and run with some output. However, you do not give enough information here for me to be certain that the output is correct according to your project's specifications.

Comment: This is what I did. All it had to do was print the owner of the vehicle

Comment: @AeriaGlorisia One reason I ask for the classes from your code is that they can provide clues to the purpose. For example, in a more "real world" example, `get()` would be something like `getOwner()` and only return the owner's name. The label `"The owner is: "` would only be added when the actual printing occurs in `main()`. As you learn more Java, you will learn more about the design concepts involved. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You need to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` simultaneously of `RegistrationPlate`.

Answer (score 2):

To use an object of `RegistrationPlate` as the key to your `HashMap`, it is advised to override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of `RegistrationPlate`. Without overriding `equals()` method the following scenario will occur:

```
RegistrationPlate rp1 = new RegistrationPlate();
RegistrationPlate rp2 = new RegistrationPlate();

rp1.equals(rp2); // returns false
```

When you override `equals()` you also need to override `hashCode()`. Without that you will find inconsistency in the behavior of the `HashMap` because of the following scenario:

```
RegistrationPlate rp1 = new RegistrationPlate();
RegistrationPlate rp2 = new RegistrationPlate();

rp1.equals(rp2); // returns true (because you overriden equals() method to be so)
rp1.hashCode() == rp2.hashCode(); // will be evaluated to false
```

Answer (score 0):

`boolean equals(Object obj)` and `int hashCode()` should be overriden in `RegistrationPlate` Class.

HashMap uses `hashCode()` to look for the group where the object is stored; and it uses `equals()` to search for that object.